# KeyError: False pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Look at the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("list.csv")
class_names = data.classname.unique()
for ic in class_names:
print(data['classname' == ic])
```

It says "KeywordError: False" at `print(data['classname' == ic])`

But it prints the output if classname value is given directly as shown below

```
print(data['classname'] == 'c1')
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You put the bracket in a wrong position. Must be `data['classname']==ic`

Answer (score 2):

The location of the square bracket is placed in the wrong place.

```
print(data['classname'] == ic)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print data related to a particular classname try:

```
for ic in class_names:
    print(data[data['classname'] == ic]])
```

It will return the dataframe with the `ic` classname

`data['classname']==ic` will only return a boolean series